# Docker kafka: opt folder is empty

Tags: docker

I have launched kafka and zookeeper containers using docker-compose.

Through docker desktop ui I can see both containers running. I want to check topics list,for which I need to use kafka-topics.sh which is supposed to be inside opt/kafka... folder.

But I see opt folder is empty.

What am I missing here?